# How to set Antd Divider colour

Tags: reactjs, jsx, antd

I've tried setting the style colour, background colour, and border colour. All not working the divider still using the default colour. Any tips?

```
import {Divider } from "antd";

<Divider style={{ color: "#d8d8d8" }}>or</Divider>
<Divider style={{ backgroundColor: "#d8d8d8" }}>or</Divider>
<Divider style={{ borderColor: "#d8d8d8" }}>or</Divider>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

basically adding this to custom css works

```
.ant-divider-horizontal.ant-divider-with-text-center::before,
.ant-divider-horizontal.ant-divider-with-text-center::after
{
   border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply styling to the divider component. Property like `borderLeft` should work fine.

```
<Divider style={{ borderLeft: '1px solid red' }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ant-divider` class to override the color for a divider and it should be like

```
.ant-divider{
  background-color: red;
}
```

or you can use it like

```
<Divider style={{'background-color':'blue'}}/>
```

please check here working example [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cbgs2n)

Comment: Hi.. i think it didnt work when my divider has text in the middle.

Comment: nope it still not working. but thanks for the tips. I looked into antd/dist/antd.css and found out that the color can be changed using ".ant-divider-horizontal.ant-divider-with-text-center::before"

Comment: @shalonteoh did you check with <Divider style={{'background-color':'blue'}}/> ?

Comment: Hi, your answer work when there is no text in middle.

Comment: but when there's text in middle will need to use ".ant-divider-horizontal.ant-divider-with-text-center::before"

Comment: This code does not gives the correct solution for the problem.

Comment: This is not correct. the property to override si the color of the `border`